# SetMatrix/SetFloat "vs" VSSetConstantBuffers (DirectX 11, C++)?

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl, directx-11

I have an DirectX 11, C++ application and an HLSL shader.

I set the martices for each object before rendering in that way:

```
void MyRenderable3D::render(
    MyCamera * camera, ID3D11DeviceContext * context, float time...){

    DirectX::XMMATRIX rotationMatrix = 
        DirectX::XMMatrixRotationX(rotation.getX()) * 
        DirectX::XMMatrixRotationY(rotation.getY()) *
        DirectX::XMMatrixRotationZ(rotation.getZ());

    ...

    constantsPerObject.worldViewProjection = 
        XMMatrixTranspose(worldViewProjectionMatrix);   
    constantsPerObject.world = XMMatrixTranspose(objectWorldMatrix);
    ...

    //bind constants per object to constant buffer 
        //and send it to vertex and pixel shaders
    context->UpdateSubresource(constantBuffer, 0, NULL, 
        &constantsPerObject, 0, 0);
    context->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &constantBuffer);
    context->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &constantBuffer);

    ... 
}
```

The `constantsPerObject` have all the constants per object, I also have `cbPerFrame`. In my shader I have corresponding entries:

```
cbuffer cbPerFrame
{
Light light; //own structure, few members like pos, intensity etc.
};

cbuffer cbPerObject
{
float4x4 WVP;
float4x4 World;

float4 difColor;
bool hasTexture;
bool hasNormMap;
};
```

Suddenly, I have discovered the other approach (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13435/loading-and-using-an-hlsl-shader):

```
//Set effect values indicating the handler and the data as paramters
mDSEGeometryStage->SetMatrix(mhProjection, &(camera->getProjectionMatrix()));
mDSEGeometryStage->SetMatrix(mhView, &(camera->getViewMatrix()));    
mDSEGeometryStage->SetFloat(mhFarClip, camera->getFarClip());
```

**My question is:**
It's better to "pack" all the variables, matrices etc. into few single contant buffers (per object, per frame) or set them separately, like in the example above with `SetMatrix`?

**Also, is that `SetMatrix`/`SetFloat` something "new" or older than constant buffers? Should I use them** (if so, which object and how should I create to be able to use that methods)?

Comment: For what i know, the latter approach is just a wrapped up interface that uses constant buffers underneath. It‘s the effect framework.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23534564/2065121) for info.